# bxslider plugin js and css not showing in site using autoptimize plugin

Tags: wordpress, bxslider

Installed the Autoptimized plugin then bxslider(Kiwi logo carousel plugin) js and css do not display in the site and our site logo carousel not showing properly in the site.
Please, anyone, suggest me what can I do that.

Please see this screenshot,
https://prnt.sc/obdxuk

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try uncheck the option  **also aggregate inline CSS**

[image]